# How to run the "maven-exec-plugin" in only certain modules?

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-plugin, apache-karaf, maven-profiles

We have an application with several modules that produce deployable artifacts.  We separate the "parent" hierarchy from the "module" hierarchy by having "parent poms" that only specify dependencies and "aggregator poms" that only have a list of modules.  We have one main aggregator pom that lists all of our modules, including the parent poms and the "artifact" poms.

Most of the "artifact" poms produce something that we eventually want to deploy to an OSGi server (karaf).  We'd like to be able to run a build that builds everything and also deploys each deployable module to Karaf.  We can specify the deployment with the "maven-exec-plugin".  In the parent pom for all the modules that can build a deployable artifact, we specify a profile that includes the maven-exec-plugin definition.

We run the build with "mvn clean install -Pprofilename".  This comes close to working, but it complains with warnings on the "parent poms" because they don't have anything to deploy.

I haven't tried this yet, but I'm theorizing that what might work is adding an "activation" section to the profile definition in the parent pom which specifies a property like "canDeployToKaraf".  I then thought that we would only define this property in the poms that produce an artifact that can deploy to Karaf.

Will the profile activation be considered for each module the aggregator pom attempts to build, or will it be activated or not for the entire build?  If it's the former, then it seems possible this strategy could work.  If the latter, then that won't work.

Will this work?  Is there a better way to do this?

**Addendum**:

It was just pointed out to me that it doesn't make sense to try to manually specify a profile on the command line, and then try to "not activate" the profile for certain poms.  Specifying the profile on the command line "activates" the profile.

What I really need to do is figure out how to configure the "maven-exec-plugin" in the parent pom so its behavior in child poms is appropriate.  In child poms that have something to deploy to Karaf, but in child poms that don't produce a deployable artifact, it does nothing.

Does anyone see a way to do that?

Comment: Hmph. Profiles can't be activated based on maven properties set in a pom.  Grumble.

Comment: profiles can be activated based on properties set in a pom: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html

Comment: Ok, that seems pretty clear.  Is it possible this wouldn't work if this profile was defined in a pom, but the property was defined in a pom that declares this pom as a parent?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably a misuse of profiles, but I won't be pushy :)

So, rather than handling the actual execution of the plugin in the parent, I would use the "plugin management" element to manage configuration of the exec plugin from the parent levels.  Then I would add the plugin delcaration to each pom that actually has something to deploy.

If you are concerned that this isn't as much resuse, because my solution creates plugin elements across all of the children that need it, consider this --  it's the config of the exec plugin that you want to "reuse".  Also, I personally believe it's much more readable; my litmus test for pom readability is that you can read a pom and know what it does at build time -- not so easy if its inheriting it's plugin execution.

Comment: I considered that approach, but we don't want to unconditionally deploy to Karaf, that's why we put it in a profile.

Comment: I guess we can mitigate this by defining the exact same profile in each child pom, which references the plugin.  I don't like that, but that may be the best compromise.

Comment: What's the general nature of the reasons you don't always want to deploy to karaf?

Comment: Well, Karaf might not be running locally, or we just want to validate that the build succeeds, or we're doing a server build just to generate snapshot artifacts tp deploy to our intranet repo.

Comment: Perhaps then you just need different continuous integration build jobs that execute against different maven lifecycle goals.  Then, you only hit the deploy goal when the build is in the CI job that is suppposed to put it in karaf, it uses the deploy goal.

Comment: Good idea, but we're presently using the "deploy" phase to upload our artifacts to the intranet repo.  It almost seems like we want to define a new phase that would be scheduled at the same point in the lifecycle as "deploy".

Comment: So, I think the repo definitions are valid targets of profiles; in fact, they kind of speak to this class of use case in the maven profiles page on teh maven site.  You could have a profile that defines the different repos, e.g. the karaf server versus the intranet repo, and the build job for karaf can simply point to the profile that declares karaf as your repo.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost.  I don't understand that.

Comment: Make a profile that defines the repositories differently for the two situations, one that declares the karaf as the deployment repo and one that declares your local repo.  Set up two separate build jobs with the only diffence being that you pass -P into the command line pointing at the appropriate profile.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: You know that Karaf isn't a Maven repository, right?  It's an OSGi container.  We use the exec plugin to deploy OSGi artifacts to Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<pluginManagement>` section to configure the plugins you want to use throughout your project. Having a list of plugins in the `<pluginManagement>` section only configures them but does not activate them. Now you can activate the plugin in a certain module by listing it in the `<plugins>` section of that modules pom. You'll only need to list the `groupId` and `artifactId`. No version, no config, that will be inherited from the `<pluginManagement>` section.

This way you can centralize the configuration of plugins, while giving every module the freedom to choose which plugins to activate.